# How to set bound when running the fable package ETS exponential smoothing state space model?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, fable

I have 32 months of data, and I'm trying out different models for testing the forecasting of unit transitions to dead state "X" for months 13-32, by training from transitions data for months 1-12. I then compare the forecasts with the actual data for months 13-32. The data represents the unit migration of a beginning population into the dead state over 32 months. Not all beginning units die off, only a portion. I understand that 12 months of data for model training isn't much and that forecasting for 20 months from those 12 months should result in a wide distribution of outcomes, those are the real-world limitations I usually grapple with.

I am using the fable package ETS model and would like to know how, or if it's possible, to set bounds for outputs when running simulations based on ETS. When I go to https://fable.tidyverts.org/reference/ETS.html to research setting bounds, the bounds argument as duplicated in the image below (perhaps I misunderstand what is meant by "bounds"), but those instructions don't say how to actually specify the lower and upper bounds:

[image]

When I run ETS on my data and plot out the forecast I get the following, where the forecast mean (in blue) at least visually reasonably hews to the actual data for those same months 13-32 (in black)(I have run other tests of residuals and autocorrelations, as well as run the benchmark methods recommended in the book, and this Holt's linear method looks fine based on those tests):

[image]

However, when I run simulations using that ETS model (code is presented at the bottom with simulation function flagged by `#`), I often get a maximum of transitions into dead state X for the forecast horizon (aggregate forecasted transitions during months 13-32) in excess of the beginning number of elements, which totals 60,000. In other words, there is no real-world scenario where transitions to dead state can exceed the beginning population! Is there a way to set an upper bound on the forecast distribution and the simulations so the total forecast doesn't exceed the cap of 60,000 possible transitions? While maintaining objective statistical integrity without injecting too much judgment?

I use a log-transformation of the data to prevent the forecast from falling negative. Negative value transitions aren't a real-world possibility for this data.

Below is the code for generating the above, and running simulations, including the dataset:

```
library(dplyr)
library(fabletools)
library(fable)
library(feasts)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(tsibble)

# my data
data <- data.frame(
  Month =c(1:32),
  StateX=c(
    9416,6086,4559,3586,2887,2175,1945,1675,1418,1259,1079,940,923,776,638,545,547,510,379,
    341,262,241,168,155,133,76,69,45,17,9,5,0
  )
) %>% 
  as_tsibble(index = Month)

# fit the model to my data, generate forecast for months 13-32, and plot
fit <- data[1:12,] |> model(ETS(log(StateX) ~ error("A") + trend("A") + season("N")))
fc <- fit |> forecast(h = 20)
fc |>
  autoplot(data) +
  geom_line(aes(y = .fitted), col="#D55E00",
            data = augment(fit)) +
  labs(y="Unit transitions", title="Holt's linear method for transitions to dead state X") +
  guides(colour = "none")

# run simulations and show aggregate nbr of transitions for months 13-32
sim <- fit %>% generate(h = 20, times = 5000, bootstrap = TRUE)
agg_sim <- sim %>% group_by(.rep) %>% summarise(sum_FC = sum(.sim),.groups = 'drop')
max(agg_sim[,"sum_FC"])
```

Comment: The bounds for ETS are referring to bounds on the parameters of the model (coefficients) and not the possible forecast values. To bound the forecasts you can consider using a transformation - a `log()` transformation will ensure forecasts are positive, and a scaled logit transformation will ensure the values fall between an upper and lower bound (https://fable.tidyverts.org/articles/transformations.html).

Comment: More likely here is that your model is inappropriate for the structure in the data you describe. For example, if your data is monotonically decreasing (alive transitioning to dead, but no possible increase in the 'alive' state) then you should consider a model which cannot produce an upward trend.

Comment: The unit transitions to dead state follow an exponential decay curve. In real-life examples of this sort of data, the curve can be less pronounced (more deaths later in time), and the curve can start ticking up in later periods as deaths begin increasing, making a more U-shape for the overall curve. I didn't find the distribution in the posted image disturbing. If you can suggest any other models to explore, I'm open. I'm now exploring simple (mean, naive, drift), ETS, ARIMA, and neural networks. A scaled logit transformation makes absolute sense too, will try that next.

Answer (score 1):

I ran the scaled logit transformation which offers a good solution, see https://otexts.com/fpp3/limits.html. However, observing Mitchell's 2nd comment "*...likely here is that your model is inappropriate for the structure in the data*", I explored this point further and am getting better results with a log-transformed ETS(M,A,N) model as opposed to the log-transformed ETS(A,A,N) model presented in the OP. The results are more reasonable with log-transformed ETS(M,A,N) than scaled-logit tranformed ETS(M,A,N). Using log ETS(M,A,N) I get the below point and interval forecast:

[image]

Researching ETS(M,A,N) further, there is a view that the conditional distribution from these "class 2" models is not Gaussian, so there are no formulae for the prediction intervals from these models although in some cases the Normal distribution might be used as an approximation for the real one, but simulations should generally be preferred. Therefore, running simulations for this data results in the following histogram which I take comfort from because the forecast simulated mean is a bit higher than actuals which is a desired outcome for the end purposes of this simulation, and the extreme outliers and what looks like a lognormal distribution is to be expected for this type of data which can be summarized as, when things go wrong in this process, they can go EXTREMELY BAD (outcomes can be really bad but never really good, sadly):

[image]

Below is code for the above (using packages from OP):

```
testDF <- data.frame(
  Month =c(1:32),
  StateX=c(
    9416,6086,4559,3586,2887,2175,1945,1675,1418,1259,1079,940,923,776,638,545,547,510,379,
    341,262,241,168,155,133,76,69,45,17,9,5,0
  )) %>% as_tsibble(index = Month)

fit <- testDF[1:12,] |> model(ETS(log(StateX) ~ trend("A")))

fit |>
  forecast(h = 20) |>
  autoplot(testDF) +
  labs(title = "Transition forecast versus actual data", 
       y = "Unit transitions",
       x = "Months 13-32 are forecast periods")

sim <- fit |>  generate(h = 20, times = 5000, bootstrap = TRUE)

agg_sim <- sim |> 
  as.data.frame() |> 
  group_by(.rep) |>  
  summarise(sumFC = sum(.sim),.groups = 'drop')

agg_sim %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = sumFC)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 50) +
  geom_vline(
    aes(xintercept = mean(as.data.frame(agg_sim)[,"sumFC"]), 
        color = "forecast period simulation mean"),
    linetype="solid", 
    size=1.5)+
  geom_vline(
    aes(xintercept = sum(as.data.frame(testDF[13:32,"StateX"])), 
        color = "forecast period actual data"
    ),
    linetype="solid", 
    size=1.5) +
  scale_color_manual(
    name = "Vertical lines:", 
    values = c(
      'forecast period actual data' = "blue", 
      'forecast period simulation mean' = "red"
      )
  ) +
  labs(title = "Histogram of simulations during forecast months 13-24", 
       x = 'Cumulative transitions during forecast period',
       y = 'Bin counts')+
  theme(legend.position = c(0.75,0.85)) +
  xlim(0, 20000)
```